# DBeaver Equivalent of "Other Users" from SQLDeveloper?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, dbeaver

I've switched over from SQLDeveloper to DBeaver. What is the equivalent of "Other Users" from SQLDeveloper in DBeaver?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out. It's under Schemas.